# Why is return values of dynamic programming function behaving weirdly

Tags: python, recursion

```
triangle = [[2],[3,4],[6,5,7],[4,1,8,3]]

def solve(tri, i, j, path):
    if j == len(tri) - 1:
        return tri[j][i]

    path += tri[j][i]
    path1 = path + solve(tri, i, j + 1, path)
    path2 = path + solve(tri, i + 1, j + 1, path)
    print(path1, path2)
    return min(path1, path2)


print(solve(triangle, 0, 0, 0))
```

answers is supposed to be 11, but it is returning 18. From printing the paths, it is clear that it does arrive at the solution of 11, but it doesn't fully return it. And instead the code keeps going and returns 18, which is the minimum of the final two paths. I cannot understand why it's doing that.

Also, I tried modifying the code such that it would simply store the lowest value instead (kind of a hack). But when doing that, I faced a much stranger problem:

```
def minimumTotal(triangle: List[List[int]]) -> int:
    lowest = float('inf')

    def solve(tri, i, j, path):
        if j == len(tri) - 1:
            return tri[j][i]

        path += tri[j][i]
        path1 = path + solve(tri, i, j + 1, path)
        path2 = path + solve(tri, i + 1, j + 1, path)
        ans = min(path1, path2)
        nonlocal lowest
        lowest = min(ans, lowest)
        return ans

    print('l', lowest)
    solve(triangle, 0, 0, 0)
    print('r', lowest)
    return lowest
```

In this case, after doing the solve function, the "print('r', lowest)" correctly prints 11 as the answer. And the line that directly follows is to return lowest. So it should return lowest. But instead, it returns float('inf'). But this only happens on the leetcode IDE (this question is leetcode 120, triangle). I think it must be something to do with the class structure of the solution template. However, pycharm does tell me that the "minimumTotal" function "Expected type 'int', got 'float' instead" as the return value, so it is registering that it's returning infinity.

Comment: Are you sure this is dynamic programming? This looks more like a BFS to me.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve in a sentence or two. I am not sure how the list relates to a triangle or a path.

Comment: you say you are returning an int in the second blob, but you are potentially returning a float since lowest is always a float('inf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing two ways to perform a depth first traversal:

- preorder, where you accumulate a path, and pass it on, and at the base case return that path
- postorder, where you have the base case return the leaf value and you accumulate this into a path while unwinding recursion.

But your code is doing a mix of both, and so suffers from double counting:

`path1` and `path2` represent a complete path, yet after the `return` statement returns one of these, the caller adds to this *again* a `path` (which it had already passed along as argument, and served to construct `path1` and `path2` there).

The second snippet has another problem as well: it doesn't update `lowest` when the input has one row only, like `triangle=[[2]]`. In that case the base case hits immediately, and `solve` exits without ever setting `lowest`. As a consequence the function returns the wrong answer, which also isn't an `int`, but a float (`inf`).

Here is the corrected version that takes the preorder approach:

```
def solve(tri, i, j, path):
    path += tri[j][i]
    if j == len(tri) - 1:
        return path
    path1 = solve(tri, i, j + 1, path)
    path2 = solve(tri, i + 1, j + 1, path)
    return min(path1, path2)
```

And here is the postorder approach:

```
def solve(tri, i, j):
    val = tri[j][i]
    if j == len(tri) - 1:
        return val
    path1 = val + solve(tri, i, j + 1)
    path2 = val + solve(tri, i + 1, j + 1)
    return min(path1, path2)
```

Note that this approach takes no path argument, since the path is only constructed *after* having made the recursive call.

Finally, this is not a dynamic programming solution. It will call `solve` with the same arguments multiple times, so it is not efficient. To implement dynamic programming you would need to *tabulate* results that can be reused.

Here is a spoiler with a dynamic programming solution:

> `def solve(tri):
>      dp = [0] * (len(tri) + 1)
>      for row in reversed(tri):
>          dp = [min(dp[i], dp[i+1]) + val for i, val in enumerate(row)]
>      return dp[0]`

Comment: thank you it makes more sense now. Also, do you have any ideas why the second bit of code is behaving so weirdly?

Comment: Added a paragraph in the middle of my answer about that.